# Create new files in Linux based on conditions

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file in `Linux`. This file contains table names in it.

Now I want to check this file and create files based on condition.

```
table=${}
validateTable=$(hive --database "${hivedb}" -e "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table'")
if [[ -z $validateTable ]]; then
    Add to file New_imports
else
     Add to file Already exists
fi
```

For example:

The file contains

```
table1 
table2
table3
table4
```

In the above tables `table1` and `table2` are already existing.

So I want two files

1) New_imports for tables that don't exist
2) Already exists for tables that exist

`new_imports`

```
table3
table4
```

`already exists`

```
table1
table2
```

How can I achieve my result

> > ```
> > #!/bin/bash
> > while read table ; do
> >    table=${1:1:-1}
> >    validateTable=$(hive --database "${hivedb}" -e "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table'")
> >    if [[ -z $validateTable ]]; then
> >       echo "$table" >> New_imports
> >    else
> >         echo "$table" >> Already_exists
> >    fi
> > done < tableFile
> > ```

Comment: Not sure why anyone downvoted even your original Q. Oh well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read table ; do
   table=$(echo "$table" | sed 's/[][]//g;s/'"'"'//g')
   validateTable=$(hive --database "${hivedb}" -e "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table'")
   if [[ -z $validateTable ]]; then
      echo "$table" >> New_imports
   else
        echo "$table" >> Already_exists
   fi
done < tableFile
```

Should get  your started. Making this bullet-proof and so it can accept arguments will take some more doing.

Managing the output files may take some doing. Note that with using `>>` means append, so each time you run this, you either need to delete those files, or manage them. I'd recommend keeping them with date-time stamps embedded in the file name like

```
 echo "$table" >> new_imports.$(/bin/date +%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M)
```

Also, I don't have anyway to test this with `hive`, so this is a general solution.

Comment: my table names in the file will be like `['testing_1234']`. From this I want to get `testing_1234` as the table name and pass to the script. When I do this the script doesn't read the table name please check edit part of my question

Comment: what happens if you run `hive --database "${hivedb}" -e "SHOW TABLES LIKE '['testing_1234']'"`  (or `'\['testing_1234'\]'`)  (or `'\[testing_1234\]'` (or other quotings) )  from the cmd-line. If it doesn't work, then edit your Q to show what form of `testing_1234` does work from cmd-line. I'm out for a while this evening, will try to check in as possible. Good luck.

Comment: the only form that works for `hive --database "${hivedb}" -e "SHOW TABLES LIKE testing_1234"` is `testing_1234` the hive statement does work only when the tables are like `testing_1234` it doesn't work with other quotings

Comment: but the actual value in tableFile are exactly `['testing_1234']` ? I can easily come up with a `sed` command to eliminate the extra chars, but can't you just put the "plain" names in the file to begin with? (or is this part of a larger system?, Or ...? ) . Back in a while.

Comment: yes the values in the tablefile are exactly like  `['testing_1234']`

Comment: I've added a `table=$( .... ) ` line right after the `while read table ;do` line. If that doesn't work, show exact output or error messages. Good luck.